# Express routing param seen as endpoint

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http-parameters

I am trying to get a user by id in a nodeJS, mongodb, and express app(a tutorial). What I receive in postman is that it looks for the endpoint 'user/885427r8448734', when id is equal to 885427r8448734, and it simply doesn't work. I put below 3 pics to better explain

[Postman request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJO9R.png)

[general route for the user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Steph.png)

[specific problematic route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2BRx.png)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJO9R.png

Comment: better to post your code instead of image

Comment: `http://localhost:3000/users/5effa5c6d574724090e3c357`send this  `URL` you are sending `users` at middleware, not `user`

Comment: Thanks Kedar, it solved my problem!